# Trigger that creates a row in another table that is referenced by current table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have 2 tables User and Account. I'd like to have a trigger that creates an account automatically when a user is created. Here is my code:

```
alter trigger Add_user on [user] for insert as
begin
    insert into [account] (name) values ('Main')

    declare @newAccountId int, @insertedId int
    set @newAccountId = (select scope_identity())
    set @insertedId = (select id from inserted)

    update [user]
    set accountId = @newAccountId
    where id = @insertedId
end
```

I want to have AccountId in the User table be not null however when I try and create a new user it won't let me and I get an error complaining about the not null AccountId column :(

Comment: 1. What does your account table look like? 2. Why are you hard-coding 'Main' for the name? 3. Are you aware that a trigger happens when 1 or more rows are inserted or updated? As a result, you can't store the inserted values in variables.

Comment: `inserted` and `deleted` are tables so that they can represent the results of set operations.  Designing a trigger on the assumption that they will always contain exactly one row is generally a bad plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make [user].AccountId nullable, it should work.

Also consider following things:

- does [account] table contain only column "name"? I.e. is it global
  for all users? Then why create new account for each user? If it's
  user-specific then add [account].[userId] column.
- I would recommend to write stored procedure instead of trigger (first create
  account record then user record), it's more explicit and safe. Be
  careful with triggers, it's likely to be a surprise for other
  developers that inserting user also creates account.